# Electric field and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, surfaces, vector-fields, curvature

My physic teacher said that

> In a conductor the electric field, which is non-zero only on the surface, is stronger where the curvature is bigger*.

But he did not provide a mathematical proof for this. Furthermore, I don't know the correct statement of this proposition: does curvature mean Gaussian curvature? And which are the hypotheses? Is the statement true for every equipotential surface?

I am asking for

1. The correct and complete statement;
2. The proof (or a reference for the proof).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

- That doesn't mean that the field is proportional to curvature. It means: if we pick two points A and B, and in A the curvature is bigger than in B, then the electric field in A will be stronger than in B.

Comment: I think that your physics teacher didn't have any special measure of curvature in mind, but I think that it rather should be the mean curvature than the Gaussian curvature, since the statement is valid also for a cylinder which has vanishing Gaussian curvature.

Comment: To simplify the mathematics you could first consider two isolated charged spheres of different radius $r$. Momentarily connect them together using a conductor so that they have the same potential. You can then use Gauss's Law to compare the electric field at the surface of each of the two now isolated equipotential sphere's. You could then repeat the procedure with two isolated cylinders of different radius. Perhaps the more mathematically elegant approach is to study the surface electric field of a charged ellipsoid, in both its oblate and prolate spheroidal forms, again using Gauss's Law.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205239/why-does-electrical-charge-concentrate-at-sharp-points and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43068/why-is-electric-field-strong-at-sharp-edges

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks but I'm looking for the _theorem_ and the _mathematical proof_ (complete, not just spherea)

Comment: Related video with calculation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVorHR_yJ6w&t=30m

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo the electric field of a conductor is not non-zero only on the surface of the conductor, it can be non zero outside too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation between the electric field and the curvature of the conductur is not very easy to state, as you can see in [[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09252.pdf)], and the idea can be formalized in many ways:

Green (see: [[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.0088.pdf)]) proved that

$\frac{dE}{dn}=-2kE$

where $k$ is the mean curvature, $E$ is the electric field on the conductor and $n$ is the normal to the conductor.

This equation, if integrated, would give the relation between the E.F. and curvature, but this operation is very hard, if not impossible in the general setting:

> In general there is no unique relationship between conductor curvature and surface charge density. However by restricting attention to situations for which the potential is a function of a single variable, the authors demonstrate that the magnitude of the surface charge density at any point of the conductor surface is proportional to the fourth root of the magnitude of the Gaussian curvature at this location.

*Mc Allister*

In  the specific case of ellipsoids, hyperboloids and paraboloids of rotation, the relation (founded by Liu and McAllister, see [[3](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.15010)] and [[4](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/23/3/016/meta)]) was:

$\sigma\propto k_g^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Note that $k_g$ is the gaussian curvature, not the mean curvature

Comment: So a closed surface of negative gaussian curvature cannot be charged ?

Comment: @Narasimham If a closed surface has nonpositive Gaussian curvature, then it can't be embedded into 3D Euclidean space in the first place. But at that point there's little reason to ask how it would behave according to 3D electrostatics.

Comment: @ Semiclassical: When K (symbol $k_g$ here)=0, yes. But when K<0 constant, consider configuration:  two conoidal hypo-pseudospheres connected at their cuspidal equators (with cone ends on axis of symmetry). It is a closed volume which can be embedded in 3D.

Comment: A rough sketch is attached.